# Can I extract Client Hello information using dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello?

Tags: python, ssl, client-server, handshake, dpkt

I want to parse the Client Hello message of the TLS handshake record.
I was taking a look at a code in Github that was very helpful and used dpkt library in order to parse the packets. The code is clear but I have a question about a part of the code that you can find below:

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    hello = handshake.data
    compressions = []
    cipher_suites = []
    extensions = []
    payload = handshake.data.data
    session_id, payload = unpacker('p', payload)
    cipher_suites, pretty_cipher_suites = parse_extension(payload, 'cipher_suites')
    verboseprint('TLS Record Layer Length: {0}'.format(len(handshake)))
    verboseprint('Client Hello Version: {0}'.format(dpkt.ssl.ssl3_versions_str[hello.version]))
    verboseprint('Client Hello Length: {0}'.format(len(hello)))
    verboseprint('Session ID: {0}'.format(hexlify(session_id)))
    print('[*]   Ciphers: {0}'.format(pretty_cipher_suites))
   



def unpacker(type_string, packet):
    """
    Returns network-order parsed data and the packet minus the parsed data.
    """
    if type_string.endswith('H'):
        length = 2
    if type_string.endswith('B'):
        length = 1
    if type_string.endswith('P'):  # 2 bytes for the length of the string
        length, packet = unpacker('H', packet)
        type_string = '{0}s'.format(length)
    if type_string.endswith('p'):  # 1 byte for the length of the string
        length, packet = unpacker('B', packet)
        type_string = '{0}s'.format(length)
    data = struct.unpack('!' + type_string, packet[:length])[0]
    if type_string.endswith('s'):
        data = ''.join(data)
    return data, packet[length:]
```

My question is about the unpacker() function that it is used in oder to parse information about the Client Hello such as : Cipher suites,compressions.

I don't understand what is the purpose of this function,what it does?
I also wanted to know if I can use `dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello` insted of the unpacker() function in order to extract Client Hello information such as Cipher suites,compressions etc?